# Execute function before and after variable delay in RxJava in a loop

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have an existing Java code which I want to write in RxJava. I am trying to Vibrate a device with a custom Pattern.

The custom pattern is of the format `{onTime1,offTime1,onTime2,offTime2...}` where,
the device vibrates for `onTime` milliseconds and waits for `offTime` before next vibration.

Here is my Java code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < customPattern.length - 1; i++) {
            try {
                io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_SERVICE_VIBRATION, Profile.UUID_CHAR_VIBRATION, this.getProtocol());
                Thread.sleep(customPattern[i]);
                io.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_SERVICE_VIBRATION, Profile.UUID_CHAR_VIBRATION, Protocol.STOP_VIBRATION);
                Thread.sleep(customPattern[i + 1]);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
I've implemented it in the following way as of now and it works just as expected. Is there a more optimised solution;
I have **split the array in tuples of 2 (onTime,offTime)** and I am emitting those and then I am performing all on the `Schedulers.computation()` Thread

```
Observable.fromIterable(tuple).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(
                t->{
                    //onNext Method

                    bluetoothIo.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_SERVICE_VIBRATION, Profile.UUID_CHAR_VIBRATION, Protocol.VIBRATION_WITH_LED);
                    Thread.sleep(t[0]);
                    bluetoothIo.writeCharacteristic(Profile.UUID_SERVICE_VIBRATION, Profile.UUID_CHAR_VIBRATION, Protocol.STOP_VIBRATION);
                    Thread.sleep(t[1]);
                },
                e->e.printStackTrace(),
                ()->{//onComplete}
        );
```

So, given this array as input {10,20,30,40,50},
I want to execute in the following manner

```
function1
wait(10)
function2
wait(20)
function1
wait(30)
function2
wait(40)
function1
wait(50)
function2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

1. Create a Flowable representing the on-off delay pattern
2. Create a Flowable of equal size of alternating true/false booleans indicating whether vibration should be on (or which method to call)
3. Zip the two Flowables together and produce a Flowable of Flowables where each nested Flowable takes the on-off value and invokes the appropriate method inside `doOnNext(...)`
4. Each nested Flowable subsequently delays its own value by the specified delay
5. Finally, concatenate the nested Flowables together

You should be able to copy/paste this into your IDE:

```
@Test
public void testVibrate()
{
    // Delay pattern:
    Flowable<Integer> pattern = Flowable.just(
            500,    // on
            250,    // off
            500,    // on
            250,    // off
            1000,   // on
            0 );    // off
            
    // Alternating true/false booleans:
    Flowable<Boolean> onOff = pattern
            .scan(
                    true,                                   // first value
                    ( prevOnOff, delay ) -> !prevOnOff );   // subsequent values
    
    // Zip the two together
    pattern.zipWith( onOff, ( delay, on ) -> Flowable.just( on )
            .doOnNext( __ -> System.out.println( "vibrate: " + on ))    // Invoke function based on value
            .delay( delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ))                     // Delay the value downstream
    .concatMap( on -> on )                                              // Concatenate the nested flowables
    .ignoreElements()
    .blockingAwait();
}
```

Comment: can you give more details about why Flowables must be used and highlight the differences between my approach and your approach as in why is one better than the other

Comment: @struct_dhancha By calling `Thread::sleep` you're effectively taking a thread out of the underlying thread pool. It could otherwise be used to perform some other workload within the app. Whether it's `Flowable` or `Observable` doesn't matter in this case. You can change it to `Observable`.

Comment: using delay operator will delay the emission of one value by the given time period right? So let's say that the first value is `(500ms, true)`, then the onNext method will be called after a delay of 500s, and since the `on` value is `true` , the vibrate function will be called after a delay of 500s. What I want is that vibrate function to be called immediately, then wait for 500s and then call stop function...

Comment: @struct_dhancha The delay operator affects the downstream. First invocation of doOnNext happens immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your solution works fine for me as of now :) To summarise, we are creating delays between `doOnNext()` methods...isn't it ?

Comment: @struct_dhancha yep, exactly. You end up with a `Flowable` of nested `Flowables` that perform `doOnNext` followed by a delay. You then `concatMap` the nested `Flowables`, resulting in a `Flowable` of `Booleans` that you can subscribe to, but ignore the values themselves.